# iRig Pre and Huawei P8 Lite 2017 compatibility

Tags: field-recording, preamp

I'd like to purchase an [iRig Pre XLR microphone interface](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigpre/) for recording pre-production ideas out in the field.

I'm wondering if anyone has tried this on a [Huawei P8 Lite 2017](https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/phones/p8-lite-2017/)?

I can see that it's compatible with Android, but would be good to know of any first hand experience with this particular phone model and the iRig hardware.

Comment: The iRig uses a TRRS connection which means it works like any regular headset included with a phone. What are you worried about? Quality?

Comment: @Timinycricket I did the research on TRRS connections and they're wired differently depending on manufacturer. It should be compliant with the CTIA/AHJ wiring standard, the details of which I can't find on the Huawei website. Quality is not such a concern, since it's only £30-ish I'm not expecting miracles, just less distortion and more bass than a typical mobile mic.

Comment: This says that the phones are generally CTIA/AHJ so I'd guess if not specified that's what it is https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/support/how-to/newbie-guide/?resourceId=456428